# Bash script to modify the last modified date using the file name

Tags: date, windows-scripting

I downloaded all the pictures from an old spanish social network and the Last modified date is the date that I downloaded the file instead of the real date. I would like to order all the pictures by Last modified date to upload to google photos using the correct date.

I know the real date because the image name has the date and time and I would make a script to change de last modified date using the name of the file. I don't care about the time.

Name of the file format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss.jpg"

[image: List of files to be converted]
I'm using windows, but is not a problem to install Unix to execute some bash script, because it may probabbly be easier.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/292688/1127778

Comment: Hello, I would recommend using Batch or PowerShell because Bash does not have a good, efficient way to track when files were modified or created and Windows’ Ransomware Protection might prevent WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) from succeeding unless the files were created by WSL.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `powershell $(Get-Item *Filename*).creationtime=$(Get-Date "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm am/pm")` in a batch file or command prompt to change the creation date of a file. for more information look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/292630/how-can-i-change-the-timestamp-on-a-file). In your case you could do:

```bat
for %%i in (<folder with all the files path>) do (
    set name=%%~i
    set name=%name:~0,19%
    powershell $(Get-Item %%~i).creationtime=$(Get-Date "%name:~5,2%/%name:~8,2%/%name:~0,4% %name:~11,2%:%name:~14,2%")
)
```

**Note:** I have **not** tested this since I do not have the data set for it.

Comment: Sorry, typo, I have removed the [[tag:batch-file]] tag too! as those were added only to suggest possible languages they would accept to have code written for them in.

Comment: Oh well... It was batch-file tag before I posted it

Comment: I'm aware, but being off topic is the main reason for my comment, the languages suggested were merely a side issue. I would advise that you delete your answer, although the choice is ultimately yours to make.

Comment: I see... I'm going to keep this up though.